find all movies that have the most actors in XPath1.0
suppose we have the following XML document:
<movies>
<movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <director id="n1"/>
    <actor id="n2" role="Tom Stall"/>
    <actor id="n3" role="Eddie Stall"/>
    <actor id="n4" role="Carl Fogarty"/>
    <actor id="n5" role="Richie Cusack"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Heat</title>
    <year>1995</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <director id="n6"/>
    <actor id="n7" role="Lt. Vincent Hanna"/>
    <actor id="n8" role="Neil McCauley"/>
    <actor id="n9" role="Chris Shiherlis"/>
    <actor id="n10" role="Nate"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Unforgiven</title>
    <year>1992</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Western</genre>
    <director id="n11"/>
    <actor id="n11" role="William 'Bill' Munny"/>
    <actor id="n12" role="Little Bill Daggett"/>
    <actor id="n13" role="Ned Logan"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Match Point</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <director id="n14"/>
    <actor id="n15" role="Chris Wilton"/>
    <actor id="n16" role="Nola Rice"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Lost in Translation</title>
    <year>2003</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <director id="n17"/>
    <actor id="n16" role="Charlotte"/>
    <actor id="n18" role="Bob Harris"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Marie Antoinette</title>
    <year>2006</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <director id="n17"/>
    <actor id="n19" role="Marie Antoinette"/>
    <actor id="n20" role="Louis XVI"/>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Spider-Man</title>
    <year>2002</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Action</genre>
   <director id="n21"/>
    <actor id="n19" role="Mary Jane Watson"/>
    <actor id="n22" role="Spider-Man / Peter Parker"/>
    <actor id="n23" role="Green Goblin / Norman Osborn"/>
</movie>
<!-- Artists -->
<artist id="n1">
    <last_name/>
    <first_name/>
    <birth_date>1999-02-02</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n2">
    <last_name>Mortensen</last_name>
    <first_name>Vigo</first_name>
    <birth_date>1958-01-01</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n3">
    <last_name>Bello</last_name>
    <first_name>Maria</first_name>
    <birth_date>1967-05-08</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n4">
    <last_name>Harris</last_name>
    <first_name>Ed</first_name>
    <birth_date>1950-09-10</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n5">
    <last_name>Hurt</last_name>
    <first_name>William</first_name>
    <birth_date>1950-04-04</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n6">
    <last_name>Mann</last_name>
    <first_name>Michael</first_name>
    <birth_date>1943-01-04</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n7">
    <last_name>Pacino</last_name>
    <first_name>Al</first_name>
    <birth_date>1940-07-07</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n8">
    <last_name>De Niro</last_name>
    <first_name>Robert</first_name>
    <birth_date>1943-03-03</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n9">
    <last_name>Kilmer</last_name>
    <first_name>Val</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n10">
    <last_name>Voight</last_name>
    <first_name>Jon</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n11">
    <last_name>Eastwood</last_name>
    <first_name>Clint</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n12">
    <last_name>Hackman</last_name>
    <first_name>Gene</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n13">
    <last_name>Freeman</last_name>
    <first_name>Morgan</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n14">
    <last_name>Allen</last_name>
    <first_name>Woody</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n15">
    <last_name>Rhys Meyers</last_name>
    <first_name>Jonathan</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n16">
    <last_name>Johansson</last_name>
    <first_name>Scarlett </first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n17">
    <last_name>Coppola</last_name>
    <first_name>Sofia</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n18">
    <last_name>Murray</last_name>
    <first_name>Bill</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n19">
    <last_name>Dunst</last_name>
    <first_name>Kirsten</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n20">
    <last_name>Schwartzman</last_name>
    <first_name>Jason </first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n21">
    <last_name>Raimi</last_name>
    <first_name>Sam</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n22">
    <last_name>Maguire</last_name>
    <first_name>Tobey</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>
<artist id="n23">
    <last_name>Dafoe</last_name>
    <first_name>Willem</first_name>
    <birth_date>1959-06-06</birth_date>
</artist>

using XPath 1.0, I need to return:

All movies that have the most actors:
I've tried this:

//movie[not(count(actor) < //movie/count(actor))]
//movie[count(actor) = max( //movie/count(actor))]
but they do not work in XPath 1.0. they work fine in XPath 2.0

All actors that are in the most movies


Does this answer your question? Find the maximum child count with XPath 1.0
